# How to disable HSTS in firefox when using proxy or testing

Tags: hsts

I need to disable HSTS in firefox (dev edition or regular) for testing and when using charles proxy.

From what I gather, HSTS is not user configurable according to the spec but this is ridiculous - I need a work around.

Does anyone know any way to do this in firefox (using version 116 dev edition, running on mac OS 12.6.7) - that verifiably works in year 2023 ?

Tried about:config settings (via google searches) and none of them worked.

Specifically, set this:
security.mixed_content.block_display_content -> true
security.enterprise_roots.enabled  -> true

..did not work!

Clear the history and "forget about this site"

..that did not work.